# Restoring access modifiers after a macro

Tags: c++, macros, access-modifiers

To declare a list of methods that are needed in a lot of classes in our codebase, we use a macro such as this one :

```
#define DECLARE_METHODS()             \
    public:                           \
        virtual void foo1(/*args*/);  \
        virtual void foo2(/*args*/);  \
        [...]                         \
    protected:                        \
        virtual void bar(/*args*/);   \
    public:
```

It's usually used like this :

```
class Class
{
public:
    Class();
    ~Class();

    DECLARE_METHODS();

    /*other public members*/

private:
    /*private members*/
};
```

But it has been know to cause some havoc when used like this :

```
class Class
{
public:
    Class();
    ~Class();

private:
    DECLARE_METHODS();

    /*private members*/
};
```

...as it sneakily declares a public access modifier to everything below it.

It's used thousands of times, so replacing the final public: with a private: would be too time-consuming as one would have to go over almost all of the clients to move the macro or open a public access modifier after it when applicable.
Removing all modifiers and having bar() unprotected is not an option.

Is there a way to know which access modifier is being used in a specific portion of code? Would it be possible to either assert that this macro is never used in a non-public scope, or to somehow remember and restore the correct access modifier at the end of the macro?

Comment: I'd set it back to `private` by default, and then fix the code that breaks. Actually, I probably wouldn't write a macro like this in the first place because I doubt that there's a way to restore the original specifier.

Comment: Perhaps a public [virtual] "interface" base class that includes the required declarations would be a better option than a macro... There other ways to skin that cat, as well, but picking the best one would require considerably more domain information. And any of them would probably be considerable work at this point. But I think any solution to your current situation is going to require a certain amount of effort...

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No

Reason: Macro expansion is fully completed by the pre-processor before any of the c++ even begins to be interpreted as c++.

This means that the pre-processor is blind to the code - it could be java, c, text, even python (if you didn't comment it) and the pre-processor would happily expand macros.

What you want to do can be achieved through the curiously recurring template pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

For example, this is how ATL automatically implements common COM interfaces for you.

Answer (score -2):

Edit: this actually doesn't work, retracted.

Haven't checked this (I don't use `private`) but try:

```
#define DECLARE_METHODS() \
    public virtual void foo1(/*args*/); \
    public virtual void foo2(/*args*/); \
    [...] \
    protected virtual void bar(/*args*/); \
    /* done */
```

This (should) avoid changing the visibility specifier for subsequent members.

Comment: Although this works in C#, it doesn't in C++. At least in MSVC you'll get a syntax error.

Comment: @StefanLundmark, odd... I did check it later (with gcc; msvc doesn't compile C++ any more than g++ compiles C) and it worked, but now it seems not to any more.

Comment: On further thought, I think I must have had `#define private /* piss off */` or somthing to that effect when I 'tested' this.